# Adding a command line call on Macbook startup

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

I'm running the latest Sierra version, and every time I reboot I need to execute

`mysql.server start`

I'd like to simply add this command to a startup script, but I've spent an hour looking at setting up daemons, etc, but I feel like it shouldn't be that difficult.

Is there an easy way to put this in some sort of startup script so every time I start my macbook it's run in the background?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

run this in terminal

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

providing that mysql installed with brew

Comment: Thanks @argoden, apparently was not installed by homebrew, on executing the second line I got `/Users/MKadlec/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist: No such file or directory`